# How to remove null values from multiple columns without loosing data in other rows

Tags: sql, hiveql

Suppose I have two columns like

```
basis_adjutment     participant_pct
123                 null
456                 null
789                 null
null                5678
null                90465
null                25457
```

I want the resultant output like

```
basis_adjutment     participant_pct
123                 5678
456                 90465
789                 25457
```

Can anybody suggest how can i get this in hive,which function should i use

Comment: How do you chose which values to combine? What's the expected result if there are more (or less) of one kind of values?

Comment: In my situation the values will be always same . can you suggest which function works to achieve that

Answer (score 0):

You could use aggregation with `row_number()`:

```
select min(basis_adjutment) as basis_adjutment, min(participant_pct) as participant_pct
from (select t.*,
             (case when basis_adjutment is not null
                   then row_number() over (case when basis_adjutment is not null then 1 else 0 end) order by basis_adjutment)
                   when participant_pct is not null
                   then row_number() over (case when participant_pct is not null then 1 else 0 end) order by participant_pct)
              end) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by seqnum;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
--
declare @t varchar(128) = 'countries', --tablename
    @c_name varchar(300),
    @sql varchar(max)

declare c cursor for
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @t;


set @sql = 'select * from '+@t+' where 1=1';

open c;

fetch next from c into @c_name;
set @sql = @sql + ' AND (' + @c_name + ' IS NOT NULL';

while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
    begin
        fetch next from c into @c_name;
        set @sql = @sql + ' AND ' + @c_name + ' IS NOT NULL';
    end;

close c;
set @sql = @sql + ')';

deallocate c;


EXEC (@sql)



----------
--you can also create procedure
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.notnullcolumns
    @t varchar(128)
AS
BEGIN



declare 
    @c_name varchar(300),
    @sql varchar(max)

declare c cursor for
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @t;


set @sql = 'select * from ' + @t + ' where 1=1';

open c;

fetch next from c into @c_name;
set @sql = @sql + ' AND (' + @c_name + ' IS NOT NULL';

while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
    begin
        fetch next from c into @c_name;
        set @sql = @sql + ' AND ' + @c_name + ' IS NOT NULL';
    end;

close c;
set @sql = @sql + ')';

deallocate c;


EXEC (@sql)


END
```